# Join two repeated fields in a BigQuery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Assume the below table that has two repeated fields (product1 & product2).

[image: Table A]

What is the most efficient way to left outer join (on sku) the two repeated fields into one repeated field so that the result looks like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(product1, product2),
  array(
    select as struct sku, description, quantity
    from t.product1
    left join t.product2
    using(sku)
  ) product
from data t
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This solution turned out more efficient than unnesting alternatives. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You can `unnest()` and then reaggregate:

```
select t.*,
       (select array_agg(product)
        from (select sku, p2.description, p2.quantity
              from unnest(product1) p1 left join
                   unnest(product2) p2
                   using (sku)
             ) product
       ) as product
from t;
```